# Changing background of a div in PHP with if statements

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a widget that lets me know when a server is online of offline. It works, I need to make it so that when it is online it is green and when it is offline it is red. here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Server Widget</title>
<style>
.server-widget {
  position:absolute;
  width:5em;
  text-align:center;
  background:#333;
  border-radius:5px;
  color:#fff;
  font-family: arial;
  padding:10px;
  top:20px; left: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="server-widget">

<?php 

$ip = "google.com";
$port = "80";
$sock = @fsockopen( $ip, $port, $num, $error, 2 );

   if( !$sock ) {

   echo( "Offline" );

   }

   if( $sock ) {

   echo( "Online" );

   fclose($sock);

   }

   ?>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This simply tells me it is online or offline. I tried to use an if statement to say if the server is online then the background color is green, else be red. When the server was online it worked. But as soon as it was an offline server the widget still stayed green.
Thanks.

Comment: this runs once, checks once, unless you reload the page you will not know if a sever status has change

Comment: Thats not the point, sorry. When I put in an offline server it will stay green.
<div class="server-widget" style="
<?php
if ($ip == $sock) {
echo "background-color:#1ec033;";
} else {
echo "background-color:red;";
}
?>
">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement coloring based on your offline status, just do two things:

I. In the style block take color attribute out of the .server-widget block and specify it separately like this:

```
.offline {color: red}
.online {color: green}
```

II. After that, all that needs to do is set the offline and online class attributes using php. To do so, replace your div block code as follows:

```
<div class="server-widget <?php 
$ip = "google.com";
$port = "80";
$sock = @fsockopen( $ip, $port, $num, $error, 2 );

   if( !$sock ) {

   echo( "Offline" );

   }

   if( $sock ) {

   echo( "Online" );

   fclose($sock);

   }

   ?>">
   </div>
```

This will place an additional class offline or online in your  tag, and thus get the coloring working.

Comment: There was some formatting issue. I have updated now.

Comment: when i change the url to an offline one this does not change unless I refresh the page. It works though, thanks. is there a way i could get it to ping the server and change when the server goes offline live?

Comment: @user3486886 For that you have to change the strategy and use ajax. In that case, you may remove the <?=php?> block from here, and instead make a jQuery ajax call to backend inside a timer. The backend php should then echo the color in json format, so that the javascript can update the div class using the jQuery addClass() or removeClass() methods. The jQuery api reference is a good starting point: http://api.jquery.com/